# React-Native SafeAreaView causes weird gap on screen (Ios)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[See this screen-short](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOv4R.png)`
"react-native": "0.67.4",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.2",

i have facing weird issue on ios. whenever i first visit this screen, i get blank screen on bottom.
but navigate another screen, its disappear by it self.
`

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/handling-safe-area/#use-the-edges-prop-to-customize-the-safe-area

i have already seen their react-navigation documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same exact issue. What helped me was using the `useSafeAreaInsets` from `react-native-safe-area-context` together with ordinary `<View/>` instead of `<SafeAreaView/>`

```
    const insets = useSafeAreaInsets();
    
    return (
        <View
          style={{
              paddingTop: insets.top,
              paddingLeft: insets.left,
              paddingRight: insets.right,
            }}
        >
          {...}
        </View>
    )
```